# Which is the best OS (Ubuntu, Windows, Mac, ...) platform to develop Flex Application without headache?

Tags: apache-flex, ubuntu, performance

I believe that OS is Windows or Mac to develop Flex application without headache. I'm working on Ubuntu. I try to use **[AXDT](http://http:/axdt.org)** or **[Flex Builder 3 for linux](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/)** to develop  **[AS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript)**. But everytime i change OS to windows when i develop Flex.

What is your opinion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex Builder is of course the preferred tool for developing Flex. I haven't tried FB for Linux, but [remember reading](http://rachaelandtom.info/content/flex-builder-linux-canned-and-how-you-can-help-get-it-going-again) that it is far from being comparable to it's Windows counterpart. In fact, this is one of the main things that is tying me to Windows. Mac is not an option to me.

Answer (score -1):

OSX cause Adobe and Mac go hand in hand

Comment: As evidenced by Flash's shitty performance on Macs, Adobe skipping 64-bit support in the latest version, etc?